# Using update_option() and get_option() is echoing escaped strings

Tags: theme-options, options

I'm using the Option API for my theme settings page.  I use the $_POST data to update the options when the changes are saved.  My issue is that the strings I send get escaped and when I use this code:

```
<?php echo get_option('myOption'); ?>
```

it echoes the escaped string.

So for example, say 'myOption' = Bob's Diner

Using the above statement, it echoes Bob\'s Diner, which is definitely not what I want.

How exactly do I go about removing that backslash when I call the option on the site?

Comment: [stripslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use PHP's `stripslashes()` command:

```
<?php echo stripslashes( get_option( 'myOption' ) );
```

Comment: Oh wasn't aware of that function exists. Sweet that worked. Thank you sir!

Comment: @FranticJ3 if this answer solved your problem, then mark this answer as accepted.